# Undo iOS certificate revocation

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, undo, signing

I accidentally revoked an iOS certificate and generated a new one. Now, other applications signed by the old certificate stopped working and I don't have the chance to build new ones for using the new certificate (at least not fast enough).

Can I undo the certificate revocation? I can see both certificates, old and new in my Macbook Keychain.

Comment: you cannot undo.. You have revoked but check in your keychain whether it is valid or not

Comment: Hi Uma. It is valid till 2016 but the status is revoked: CSSMERR_TP_CERT_REVOKED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't undo the revoke. But you can create a new one and use it instead the previous and refresh the certificate in Xcode. Download the new certificate and double click on it will refresh the certificate. To be sure , from xcode->preference you should find a section "account" where you can refresh the current certificate.

Comment: Hi Lorenzo. What do you mean refresh? Basically I'm trying to fix my big mistake where other apps created by other developers stopped working. So I don't have the Xcode project for these apps, and the only way to solve this problem, at least in a fast way, seems to undo the revoke...

Comment: If you don't have the project I think is not possible to fix the issue quickly. You have to ask to the app developer to reinstall the new certificate.

Comment: You can't undo the revoke action

Comment: My company has around 15 iOS App IDs in our Apple Developer Center. Can I know the ones signed by the revoked certificate?

Comment: If you revoke a development profile automatically all provisioning profiles based on it should be regenerated with the new certificate otherwise the provisioning profile become invalid. In iTunes you should look into the provisioning profile list and see if the profiles are valid or not